# Scala how to find the max of Intgers in a List[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Let the list be

```
val list = List([80], [79], [92])
```

how to get the maximum value in scala . The list is List[Row] not List[Int]

Comment: You should add spark tag and mention you are talking about `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`.

Comment: added @PaulGeorgPodlech

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `Row` will contain only `Ints`, you can convert it to `Seq` and then apply a `max`

```
list.flatMap(_.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]).max
```

quick Example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val list: List[Row] = List(Row(1), Row(2))
List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = List([1], [2])


scala> list.flatMap(_.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]).max
Int = 2
```

**EDIT**

Edit to match the input provided by the OP

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON



 val list = List(Row("""{"name":"abc","salary":"2000","id":"1","timeStamp" : "1528725600000"}"""))



list.map(r => JSON.parseFull(r.getString(0)))
.map(x => x.flatMap[Any]({
              case x: Map[String, _] => x.get("timeStamp")
              case _ => None
          }))
.map(x => x match {
          case Some(i: String) => i 
          case _ => "" })
.max
```

- The first map will parse your json inside the row to a Map
- The second will get only the timestamp from that map
- The third map will process the timestamp wich comes as Option[Any] and convert it to String
- Finally, max will get the max value of all the received timestamps

Comment: But what if there is a foreach and I have to iterate the List[Row] object to find the max

Comment: I dont understand. The flatMap will iterate over all the elements

Comment: well, There is a predefined structure . There is a foreach loop. because the data is something like this 

val list = List(Row("""{"name":"abc","salary":"2000","id":"1","timeStamp" : "1528725600000"}"""))  .

There are several such rows. Lets assume that we are getting the key and value. I have to iterate through the loop for various reasons. while iterating the loop can i find the max of the key timestamp ?

Comment: Wow, that should be in the question. It's important to know that there will be a json inside the Row in order to answer it. 

You need to parse the json and retrieve the desired key. Then you can get the max. I'll update my answer with that

Comment: Yeah. Thank you @Scouto

Comment: No . Still stuck on that

Comment: Did you check my edit? Update your answer with your current problem

Comment: Hey @Scouto. I will check it now.  What JSON library are you using BTW ?

Comment: This one: import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON